# How to response an array in json to jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

In my code I am creating an array-list in JSON and want to response this arraylist into jquery.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){ 
list.add(i);
}
```

How can I response this list to my jquery file and get retrieve it in jquery? For a simple String I know how to response and retrieve in jquery using ajax. For example:-
**IN JSON**

```
String name ="abcd";
writer.key("nameofperson").value(name);
```

and in jquery

```
  $.ajax({
                url: baseURL + '.json', 
                dataType: 'json',
                type:'POST',
                success: function(data)
                    {
                        console.log("test sucess");
                        var ROI =data['nameofperson'];
                    alert(ROI)   
            },
```

It is working. How can i acheive the same for arraylist?

Comment: There seems to be Java in your example, not that Javascript is different than Java.  Also there seems to be confusion around running code vs. files storing code.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer without sample json , but in general  - this is what you need to do :

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer js = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
var myJson = js.Serialize(list);
```

and do this in client side :

```
 success: function(data)
                    {

                      for( var i in data )
                          {
                              alert(data[i])
                          }
                   }
```